# Solve the following question about line integral

Tags: integration, line-integrals

Given, $$\vec{F} = \nabla (4x^2+3y^4)$$

Find $$\int_{C} \vec{F}.d\vec{r}$$ where $C$ is the quarter of circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in first quadrant, rotated counterclockwise.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use the general result
$$
\int_C \nabla V\cdot d\mathbf r= V(\mathbf x_1)-V(\mathbf x_0)
$$
where $\mathbf x_0$ is the initial point of $C$ and $\mathbf x_1$ the final point.

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec F=\nabla (4x^2+3y^4)=8xi+12y^3j$$

Use polar substitution for unit circle C: $x^2+y^2=1$,  $$x=\cos\theta\implies dx=-\sin\theta d\theta\quad \text{&} \quad y=\sin\theta\implies dy=\cos\theta d\theta$$

$$\int_C\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\int_C(8xi+12y^3j)\cdot (dxi+dyj)$$$$=\int_C(8xdx+12y^3dy)$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}(-8\cos\theta\sin\theta d\theta+12\sin^3\theta \cos\theta d\theta)$$
$$=-8\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\theta\sin\theta d\theta+12\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^3\theta \cos\theta d\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec F=\nabla (4x^2+3y^4)=8xi+12y^3j$$

From equation of unit circle $C$: $x^2+y^2=1\implies dy=\dfrac{-xdx}{y}$,

$$\int_C\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\int_C(8xi+12y^3j)\cdot (dxi+dyj)$$$$=\int_C(8xdx+12y^3dy)$$
$$=\int_1^0\left(8xdx+12y(1-x^2)\left(\frac{-xdx}{y}\right)\right)$$
$$=\int_1^0\left(-4x+12x^3\right)dx$$